# Java calculator with multiple operations has string error

Tags: java

I'm using a tutorial online but it seems that it might be a bit outdated? Here it is if you guys want it: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Simple-Calculator-in-Java/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MathOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int secondNumber = 0;
        char operator;
        double answer = 0.0;

        Scanner scanObject = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
        firstNumber = scanObject.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your second number");
        secondNumber = scanObject.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Addition, substraction, multiplcation, or dividing? ");
        operator = scanObject.next().charAt(0);

        switch (operator){
            case "Addition": answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;

        }
    }

}
```

I get this error: string cannot be converted to char

Comment: `operator` is a `char`, so in what case will it be `"Addition"`?

Comment: "it might be a bit outdated?" No, you just skipped the part where the `switch` construct is using a char, not a string.

Comment: Having said that, maybe instructables is not the best source for java programming. I'd suggest you go with the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) from oracle. It's for java 8, but it applies to java 11 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MathOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int secondNumber = 0;
        char operator;
        double answer = 0.0;

        Scanner scanObject = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
        firstNumber = scanObject.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your second number");
        secondNumber = scanObject.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Addition, substraction, multiplcation, or dividing? ");
        operator = scanObject.next().charAt(0);

        switch (operator){
            case 'A': answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        }
    }

}
```

Strings cannot be converted to characters, but you were using a String as your case condition, and so it attempted to auto-cast it, throwing the error.